# Sort Access Log By Time

Tags: linux, shell, grep

access log is very important part of my job.

Is there any way by which i can sort particular request by times.

like :
grep "search" access_log | sort by time ?

We can get the time using
grep "search" access_log | awk '{print $8}'

Comment: Please post a few (anonymized) lines that you want to sort

Comment: there exists a "sort" utility which you can use to specify according which field(s) you want to sort, and it can work on (some) formats of date/time representations too

Comment: Access logs have a nice tendency to already be sorted chronologically, as they are appended for each new entry. Not sure what you mean by "sort by time" in this case...

Answer (score 0):

grep "search" access_log | awk '{print $8}' | sort